# Why does this comparator exhibit non-binary behaviour?

Tags: comparator

I'm attempting to use the TLV3501 ([Datasheet](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirgpDs68zXAhWBwJQKHUi6AIkQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Ftlv3501.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2sc7PE_CwjAJgirtFSt3ac)) with the following circuit.
[image: Circuit] 
Input at S_IN is around 2.5VDC (i.e. no waveform).

I'm expecting to see a sharp transition between rails on the output as RV1 is adjusted and the voltage at pin 2 transitions across 2.5V, like this:
[image: Expected transition]

Instead what I'm seeing is more like this:
[image: Actual transition]

I.e. I see the rail voltages at the extremities of RV1, and around the middle the output at pin 6 is more or less the same as at pin 3. If I apply a signal at S_IN I see that signal on the output.

Here is a photo of my circuit.
[image: Breadboard]

Can anybody tell me the reason for this non-binary behaviour, and what I would need to do to get the output response to resemble the first graph.
I understand that using a breadboard could cause capacitive coupling or oscillation but I would have expected that the comparator would give the expected output with only DC at the inputs. Or am I wrong?

**Edit** Scope output
[image: 0VDC out]
[image: 5VDC out]
Extremities of RV1 showing rail voltages

[image: Middle]
RV1 near the midpoint, showing around 2.5VDC out

[image: Clipped]
With a 400hz sine wave I can get the comparator to swing to one rail or the other by tweaking RV1 but not a clean switch from rail to rail.

**Edit** Scope trace of top of C1, 20mV and 10uS / div. My scope actually shows the same trace (with less amplitude) with no power applied so I'm not sure how much of this is actual noise.
[image: C1 Trace]

Scope trace of output, 20mv and 1uS / div. Looks like there is oscillation after all.
[image: Oscillation]

Comment: Do you have a scope to investigate if the output is oscillating?

Comment: How did you measure it and what is the timebase? These things have rise times, as well as your measurement equipment

Comment: First I thought _no hysteresis_, but the IC should have 6 mV of hysteresis built-in, which _should_ be enough for the setup you are testing.

Comment: @peufeu yes I have a scope, the output is not oscillating. I can post images if that will help.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am measuring the output by watching the scope as I adjust RV1.

Comment: What is the scope bandwidth? This comparator can easily oscillate at 100MHz... Also, what probe? Try adding a resistor in the output, like 50R. Do you need the speed of this comparator?

Comment: @peufeu ultimately yes I do need the speed. I plan to use it with a signals up to 18MHz. Scope bandwidth is 10MHz. If it were oscillating wouldn't I see something other than a flat line?

Comment: Probe is a standard 1x / 10x probe.

Comment: If it oscillates at 100MHz on a 10M scope I wouldn't count on the scope trigger being able to sync on it, in this case all you will see is a thickened trace, or a trace that looks a bit "funny" -- try putting a resistor like 1k in the output to reduce the current draw on switching.

Comment: You should carefully read the datasheet, especially chapter 10 Layout. The placement and connection of capacitors is important: "The location and type of capacitors used for power-supply bypassing are critical to high-speed comparators.
The suggested 2.2- μF tantalum capacitor does not need to be as close to the device as the 0.1- μF capacitor, and may be shared with other devices."
The 2.2-
μF capacitor
buffers
the power-supply
line against
ripple,
and the 0.1-
μF capacitor
provides
a charge
for the comparator
during
high-frequency
switching."

Comment: What is the rail doing on the left side of that inductor? 330uH seems a tad excessive.

Comment: @Trevor at present the left side of the inductor goes directly to a USB 5V supply, nothing else.

Comment: The other left? Show me the scope trace at the top of C1 on your schematic.

Comment: @Uwe I did the best I could by soldering C1 and C2 directly to the pins. C2 is electrolytic not tantalum. If I can't get it to work I will probably end up making a small board with surface mount components, in that case I will use the suggested layout in the datasheet. I was hoping to avoid that, at least for low-frequency operation.

Comment: @peufeu I don't see any fuzzy or thickened traces in the output. I will try your suggestion of a 1K resistor.

Comment: @Trevor I will post a scope trace tonight.

Comment: Note I'm not sure it is oscillation, it could be, or it could be something else. For such fast chips, if you want to prototype, dead bug over ground plane is a quick and rather easy way. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/331541/13616

Comment: @Trevor I've posted a trace at C1.

Comment: @peufeu when zoomed right in there does seem to be oscillation, looks like I'd better try your dead bug suggestion.

Comment: The ringing you see on the scope seems to be rather low frequency. This points to the ceramic capacitors (which have low ESR) forming a LC resonant circuit with the wiring inductance of the breadboard, which is huge. To fix this, replace C4/C6 with one electrolytic, more than 100 µF would be best to get lowish ESR. The only ceramic cap shuld be right on the chip's pins (like on your picture). However you can still get positive feedback through the supply and ground, because the breadboard's inductance is very high. A ground plane is much better...

Comment: First I'd try shorting out that inductor.

Comment: OK, next chance I get I will try the dead bug approach with a ground plane. Does this mean I need to scrap the breadboard entirely? I hope to use this with another circuit which is already working on a breadboard, can I safely connect the inputs and output to a breadboard?

Comment: @peufeu it is working well upside down with a ground plane. If you want to make your suggestion an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will post my own answer.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, I'm much more interested in seeing a nice picture of your prototype than in the reputation from an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of high-speed chip does not work on a breadboard.
After placing it upside down dead-bug style (thanks @peufeu) on a bit of scrap PCB, with the signal source next to it (and the copper foil connected to GND), I am seeing the expected output.
Connections need to be as short as possible. Even after placing it I still observed a lot of "linear", non-binary behaviour until I connected it directly to the signal source with a short wire. Prior to that I had been using a piece of audio cable about 10cm long with a phone jack connected to my phone.
Below is the component connected to the signal source (an MC44144 PLL) and the output, 0-5V at around 4.43MHz.
[image: Dead bug prototype]
[image: Output]

Comment: Nice! As for decoupling, as seen on your pic what matters is short low inductance wiring in the loop "GND - decoupling cap - VCC - chip - GND", which is what you did. A SMD ceramic cap has even lower inductance of course. I think the problem you had with the input cable could be coupling of the output into the input. If you make a real PCB for this, use what you learned on the ugly prototype ;) ground plane and short signal paths. And don't be afraid of SMD, use 1206 if you want the easiest to solder.